# How can I get rid of mold on climbing skins for skis?

Tags: skiing, backcountry, mold

There is a bit of mold on the sticky side of my mohair climbing skins for my skis. How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Some things I have used to keep my skins in good shape

1. Use mild detergent to wash the hairs with a sponge

   - Don't get this on the sticky layer
2. Spray with a 5% bleach solution and let dry, then rinse with water several hours later.
3. If mildew grows, expose the hair sides to the sun for several hours to a day.

   - UV exposure is very damaging to the mildew causing organisms.
4. Allow the skins to **dry completely** before storing over the summer.
5. Store the skins in a breathable bag, **not** sealed plastic  like a freezer bag.

### Best way to keep the mold down...

**Get out there and use your skins every few days, and go skiing!**

Mold doesn't stand a chance against the granular snow and ice adbraiding the fur for hours on a long ski tour.

Get out there and have a good time.

Answer (score 1):

Bleach or Tilex will get rid of mold, but you should try it on a small piece first to make sure it doesn't ruin the sticky glue.